# Rails 3 legacy "assets" routes

Tags: routes, asset-pipeline, assets, rails-3-upgrade

I'm in the process of upgrading from a Rails 2.3.14 app to Rails 3.2.1
So far, the only issue is an inability to specify routes to our legacy assets resources.

In **config/application.rb**:

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

The following works (with an incorrect path):

```
resources :company_assets, :controller => 'assets', :as => :assets
```

But, of course, the path is **'/company_assets/*'**.

As soon as I try to make the path so it's **'/assets/*'**, the routes fail to generate.  By **"fail to generate"**, I mean running:

```
rake routes | grep assets
```

Shows me nothing.

Here's an example of routes that fail to correctly generate:

```
resources :company_assets, :controller => 'assets', :as => :assets, :path => 'assets'

# or

resources :assets
```

When I poke around in the Rails console, it appears there are asset related routes, but they seem to be equivalent to having specified:

```
resource :assets
```

Instead of:

```
resources :assets
```

(Note singular vs. plural)

Is it possible to maintain backward compatibility here without mangling existing paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The reason this happens is because Sprockets (which handles the asset pipeline) takes over the /assets route.

You can change the route that Sprockets uses by adding this to your `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.prefix     = "/x"
```

Where x is the new route.

I do this in one of my production apps because paperclip was storing its files in /assets.

One tip for upgrading: check the pipeline settings in your upgraded app against those in the [last section of the asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails).